# JavaScript form validation for ensuring a date of birth is 4 digits long

Tags: javascript, regex, string, forms, validation

I'm trying to ensure a valid date of birth by making sure it's 4 characters long and every character is a digit.

```
function validateBirth() {
    var year = document.forms["myForm"]["birth_year"].value;
    if (year.match(/\A\d{4}\z/) !== null) {
      alert("Date of birth must be 4 digits");
      return false;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to use JavaScript's `string#match` function to search for a regular expression in a value. Here we know that it must contain 4 digits, but that it also must not contain any non-digits.

For example, a string like `a4b456` would be invalid. That's why I used the regex tags `\A` and `\z` for starting and ending a string respectively.

When I test out this function in jsconsole, it looks like this

```
var year = "1958"
year.match(/\A\d{4}\z/)
=> null
```

I tested the exact same regex in rubular and learned that there was a match. Am I getting crazy, or is there something here I'm missing?

I know I can do this using `HTML Input Validation`, but that won't work on non-modern browsers so I need to use the JavaScript method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start and end of a string for a JavaScript regex are `^` and `$` respectively. (`\A` and `\z` are valid for start and end in Ruby, but not JavaScript.) So this regex will work:

```
year.match(/^\d{4}$/);
```

If you're interested in a Boolean result rather than receiving the actual match, you can do this instead:

```
/^\d{4}$/.test(year)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expression:

```
var year = +(document.forms.myForm.birth_year.value);
var yearchk = !isNaN(year) && year/1000 || 0.5;
if (yearchk >= 1 && yearchk < 10) { /** it's ok **/ }+
```